# How to setup biblatex to not capitalise first author last names

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, biber, biblatex-chem

I have a problem with german names with prefix in my bibliography. If the first author surname starts with a small letter, the name gets capitalised anyway. This is not a problem for the second author, etc... It can be fixed putting curly braces around the name in the .bib file, but unfortunately, my citation manager exports the .bib file like this.

Does anybody have an idea, how to fix it? I would be very greatful!

A MWE is here:

```
\documentclass[british]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    
\usepackage{babel}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=chem-acs,maxbibnames=10,articletitle=true]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
    @book{Test1,
        author = {von Kling, Alfred and von Klade, Otto},
        booktitle = {This is just a test},
        title = {{This is just a test}},
        year = {2012}
    }
    
    @book{Test2,
        author = {{von} Kling, Alfred and von Klade, Otto},
        booktitle = {This is just a test2},
        title = {{This is just a test2}},
        year = {2012}
    }
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
    
    % !TEX TS-program = pdflatex
    % !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode 
    % !BIB TS-program = biber
    
    Doesn't work. \autocite{Test1,Test2}
    
    \printbibliography
    
\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image: outcome]

Comment: The _name prefix_ (here `von`) must be capitalized at the start of a sentence. You can try the `useprefix=false` option to get "Kling, A. von" (cf. Bilatex documentation, p. 72).

Comment: Yes, but unfortunately, my Professor starts with a "von" and does not want his name capitalised in the bibliography. Moreover, it is not a prefix but part of the surname, so it should not come after the whole name.  But moewe already answered my question perfectly! Thank you for participation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the idea is that the start of a new bib entry is sort of like the start of a sentence. Even a "von" is usually capitalised at the start of a sentence, so it is natural that the "von" would be capitalised here as well.

If you do not want this behaviour, you can tell `biblatex` not to treat the start of a bibliography entry like the beginning of a sentence by issuing `\midsentence` in `begentry`.

```
\documentclass[british]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=chem-acs, maxbibnames=10, articletitle=true]{biblatex}

\renewbibmacro*{begentry}{\midsentence}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{Test1,
  author    = {von Kling, Alfred and von Klade, Otto},
  booktitle = {This is just a test},
  title     = {This is just a test},
  year      = {2012}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
  Doesn't work. \autocite{Test1}

  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: von Kling, A.; von Klade, O., This is just a test, 2012.]

Or you tell `biblatex` never to capitalise the "von" at the beginning of a sentence.

```
\documentclass[british]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=chem-acs, maxbibnames=10, articletitle=true]{biblatex}

\renewbibmacro*{name:family}[4]{%
  \ifuseprefix
    {\usebibmacro{name:delim}{#3#1}%
     \usebibmacro{name:hook}{#3#1}%
     \mkbibcompletenamefamily{%
       \ifdefvoid{#3}
         {}
         {\mkbibnameprefix{#3}\isdot
          \ifprefchar{}{\bibnamedelimc}}%
       \mkbibnamefamily{#1}\isdot}}
    {\usebibmacro{name:delim}{#1}%
     \usebibmacro{name:hook}{#1}%
     \mkbibcompletenamefamily{%
       \mkbibnamefamily{#1}\isdot}}}%

\renewbibmacro*{name:family-given}[4]{%
  \ifuseprefix
    {\usebibmacro{name:delim}{#3#1}%
     \usebibmacro{name:hook}{#3#1}%
     \mkbibcompletenamefamilygiven{%
       \ifdefvoid{#3}
         {}
         {\mkbibnameprefix{#3}\isdot
          \ifprefchar{}{\bibnamedelimc}}%
       \mkbibnamefamily{#1}\isdot
       \ifdefvoid{#4}
         {}
         {\bibnamedelimd\mkbibnamesuffix{#4}\isdot}%
       \ifdefvoid{#2}
         {}
         {\revsdnamepunct\bibnamedelimd\mkbibnamegiven{#2}\isdot}}}
    {\usebibmacro{name:delim}{#1}%
     \usebibmacro{name:hook}{#1}%
     \mkbibcompletenamefamilygiven{%
       \mkbibnamefamily{#1}\isdot
       \ifdefvoid{#4}
         {}
         {\bibnamedelimd\mkbibnamesuffix{#4}\isdot}%
       \ifboolexpe{%
         test {\ifdefvoid{#2}}
         and
         test {\ifdefvoid{#3}}}
         {}
         {\revsdnamepunct}%
       \ifdefvoid{#2}
         {}
         {\bibnamedelimd\mkbibnamegiven{#2}\isdot}%
       \ifdefvoid{#3}
         {}
         {\bibnamedelimd\mkbibnameprefix{#3}\isdot}}}}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{Test1,
  author    = {von Kling, Alfred and von Klade, Otto},
  booktitle = {This is just a test},
  title     = {This is just a test},
  year      = {2012}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
  Doesn't work. \autocite{Test1}

  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

The output in this MWE is the same, but you will see a difference if you use, say `\Textcite{Test1}` at the start of a sentence.

Comment: Thank you very much! Perfect answer!